# http://magento.local reverts to live site - Magento and Xampp for OSX

Tags: mysql, apache, magento, xampp, base-url

I'm having trouble trying to rebuild my dev environment.

I've installed XAMPP and followed these steps:

1. Backup MYSQL DB.
2. Backup Home Directory.
3. Create DB with same user/dbname
4. Imported SQL file successfully, and imported home directory (and invisible files) into htdocs.
5. Verified that base_url and secure_base_url are set to "http://magento.local" (I have tried http://127.0.0.1, also)
6. Deleted all Cache/Sessions

How can i get http://magento.local to just display my local website, instead of reverting to the live URL?

I have edited my base_urls, and even the cookie url.

Comment: Never tested with `localhost`, but doesn't Magento need a [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) to work properly?

Comment: Even when using something like http://magento.local
with the hosts added, It still reverts. I've removed every instance of the URL from the database.

Comment: @danchet you didn't mentioned about installation technique. Did you install fresh magento installarion first or just replace the content from production server?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that, I copied the production DB into an empty DB on OSX.

Comment: Are you the only one who made changes to this instance of Magento? because it is possible that there is hard coded string in the code for the live site URL. Also, try to debug the script by putting break point on different part of the script until you find the line of code that cause the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I always do it is as follows...

Search the core_config_data table for ANY fields that are URLs, which you can do by running...

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE value LIKE 'http%'
```

..or simply using phpMyAdmin if you have it available. One of our main sites has a total of about 8 rows to be updated (possibly not all required, could be left from older versions it was running on). If you see your live URL simply change it out for your local address.

Then open you cache folder and delete any files starting with mage--*. The thing that normally ends up catching me out at this point is file permissions. I don't know what OS you are using, so I can't tell you how to check, but if the apache user doesn't have write permissions to the cache folder the first time you accessed the site, Magento creates most of the files normally created in the DOCUMENT_ROOT/var folder in the OS's temp directory. For example, we use Mac OSX at work, it will create the cache files in /tmp/magento/, upon deleting that directory you should be good to go.

NB: You should probably update the file permssions of the var directory before viewing the site again, otherwise it will keep writing to the temp directory, which will trip you up again in the future.

Comment: Changing my permissions on var did it! Thanks!

Comment: np, that little nugget has had me scratching my head on numerous occasions :)

Comment: I'll award bounty in a few hours, when I am able.

Comment: Also- Any reason why when i change it back to 755, it reverts to the live URL again?

Comment: Assumably your Apache (or whatever server your using), is not running as the owner, since the group/everyone can't write to the file it would revert to the tmp directory. If you haven't deleted the contents of /tmp/magento, this would still use the old value, if you have, then I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Magento is loading, noting that the URL you're using is not the same as what's configured, and redirecting you.

[Here are](http://blog.chandanweb.com/magento/how-to-change-base-url-in-magento) the steps to edit the base URL in the Magento config.

I'm guessing you need to clear the Magento cache mentioned there.

Comment: Thanks, but as my question stated- I have taken these steps prior to experiencing this.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your htaccess file?

Comment: Where in my htaccess file would it automatically load a URL?

Comment: We have to see your htaccess file first to answer. Seems it runs a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 2):

If your **local** magento store url is like *http://magento/* then your Magento dont work, but if your url is like *http://magento.local/* - magento store will be working fine.

Comment: I set it up like this, but it still reverts to the live site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try clearing your Magento cache to start. Also note that some browsers cache redirects, so try accessing the site in a different browser or clearing the browser cache.

Comment: Tried this method, and i'm still only getting the live site.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have set the base_url .you can actually edit it in the phpmyadmin look for the table with **'config_data'** on its name.

> localhost/text.html = test.html [correct]

of course it will be correct since it doesn't pass through the 'index.php' which works as the controller. remember that magento uses clean urls too.

> www.yourdomain.com/index.php/name_for_the_page/

Comment: The base URL & secure Base URL is http://magento.local - I have removed the live URL from almost every record in the DB, cleared my browser cache and dumped any cache folders or sessions in var. I removed the entire contents of var and I still revert to the live site. No clue.

Answer (score 1):

If your core_config_data is right, then this is very likely an issue with your local.xml file. Be sure your database information being supplied to this file is correct.

**httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml**

```
<default_setup>
        <connection>
            <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
            <username><![CDATA[your_username]]></username>
            <password><![CDATA[your_password]]></password>
            <dbname><![CDATA[your_db]]></dbname>
            <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
            <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
            <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
            <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
            <active>1</active>
        </connection>
 </default_setup>
```

In this case your core_config_data is just fine, it's just not using the right core_config_data table. I ran into this same problem when my staging database was named differently than my local. A simple "Oops!" mistake.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, this is something I'll make sure to lookout for in the future.